# How do I use ffmpeg4android in an ADT project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I used the project FFmpeg4Android on sourceforge to build the FFmpeg .so shared library files. However, I am having trouble using them in an ADT Java application. I created a simple JNI call that attempts to call av_register_all and I get library errors.

When I run the application on my Nexus 7 I am told that it is unable to load library libavformat-HEAD-1.0.so

So I tried to load this via the System.loadLibrary method and I was unable to find libavcodec-HEAD-1.0.so. Working my way back in this manner I eventually attempted to load libavutil-HEAD-1.0.so which yielded an error 'cannot locate symbol "__strchr_chk"'.

This is my Java class:

```
public class LibavcodecTest {
    public static native void avRegisterAll();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("avutil-HEAD-1.0");
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec-HEAD-1.0");
        System.loadLibrary("avformat-HEAD-1.0");
        System.loadLibrary("LibavcodecTest");
    }
}
```

**Update**

I contacted the developer that maintains ffmpeg4android and he was able to direct me to change the version of the android source I was building against to the same as my device which worked to allow my to call av_register_all successfully.

However, now I get a crash calling avformat_open_input where I receive "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)".

My search on the web makes me believe this is a memory access issue. Does anybody know if this may be resolved by loading the shared libraries differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to getting the built shared libraries to work on my device was to build the source on an older NDK that was compatible with it.  I was attempting to build it on the latest source and that did not work.

[Here is a link to the discussion I had with the developer who helped me solve it.](https://sourceforge.net/p/ffmpeg4android/discussion/general/thread/7bdf1dd8/?limit=25#aac9)